# Can I use proof of onward travel that assumes a visa extension?

Tags: visas, thailand, paperwork

I'm applying for a multiple-entry tourist visa for Thailand.  The visa will net me 2 entries of up to 60 days each, **but** once I'm in the country, I can extend my visa by 30 days each time.

As part of the visa application process, I have to show proof of onward travel for each entry.

Do I have to book flights that depart within 60 days of each entry to use as proof of onward travel (and then change my flights when I get my visa extended)?

Or can I go ahead and book flights departing within 90 days after each entry and submit those with my visa application?

Comment: I believe that if there is no procedure to right away apply for the 90 day visa and the embassy advises you to get a visa extension later, there would be no harm in doing so. You might want to call up the embassy regarding the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to speak with the Embassy or Consulate handling your visa application, as technically the visa is only 60 days. The 30 day extension is granted afterwards and is at the discretion of the Immigration Officer you speak with in Thailand.  While the extension is usually easy to get, it is not guaranteed.

Also your visa would allow you only 60 days in country and if the air ticket says 90 days, the airline is not supposed to allow you to board the flight.

While you may hear from folks that say they got around these rules, they are in effect and could be enforced without leeway.